# What is and what isn't considered an oscillation? And why?

Tags: classical-mechanics, definition, oscillators

If oscillations are periodic motions, is circular motion of an object with constant velocity also considered an oscillation, even though absolute value of its velocity and its acceleration are constant through the whole time?

Comment: most certainly, if you keep track of the x and y coordinates of an object going in a circle at a constant angular speed, you shall find that both x and y are evolving sinusoidally. Pretty much the most canonical oscillation you can get

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.